# Sent messages coming back in XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, asmack

I have implemented chatting in android using aSmack library. Issue that I am facing is that, I am getting back the messages that I send to other user if the other user is not logged in to XMPP. It does not happen always, but only after sending too many messages, then I start to receive the same message I am sending to other user, as it is from other user.

I have checked the user ID, and it shows that the message is from the other user.Everything works perfectly when the other user is logged in.

Please help me to find a solution to this issue.

Comment: Do the messages you receive have a `type` attribute of `error`?  Many XMPP servers return failed messages in their entirety, with just the `type` attribute changed and an error condition element added.

Comment: @legoscia: I have used latest asmack jar and issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

check storage policy and storage store max size for openfire server.

> Store - Store offline messages for later retrieval. Messages will be delivered the next time the recipient logs in. Choose a storage policy and storage store max size below.

```
**Store or Bounce - Store messages up to the max storage size. After the max size has been exceeded, bounce the message back to the sender.**
Always Store - Always store messages, even if the max storage size has been exceeded.
Store or Drop - Store messages for a user up to the max storage size. After the max size has been exceeded, silently drop messages.
```

Per-user offline message storage limit:   KB
    Bounce - Never store offline messages and bounce messages back to the sender.
    Drop - Never store offline messages and drop messages so the sender is not notified.